# Java -> eraser for freehand drawing (vector), like IncrementalStrokeHitTester in C#

Tags: java, javafx

I´m trying to create a freehand painting app in JavaFx. I created an onMouse drag event, that creates 2d Points and connects the Points with a Line, when the user moves the mouse.

```
path = new Path();
path.setStrokeWidth(10);
path.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

...

EventHandler<MouseEvent> mouseHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {        
          path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
        } else if (mouseEvent.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo(mouseEvent.getX(), mouseEvent.getY()));
        }
    }       
};
```

Now i would like to add an **eraser-tool**, which looks if it intersects with the line and deletes the nearest Path-Point. When i use the JavaFx intersects method it can only handle the boundingBox of the node which is very unprecise.

C# got the "IncrementalStrokeHitTester" method which hittests the stroke with the Mouse/Eraser. Is there any similiar method i could use for my Eraser-tool?